# Replace decimal numbers in string by hex equivalent

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a huge set of strings like:

```
// Register 10:
typedef struct RegAddr_10
{
  uint8 something: 4;
  uint8 something_else: 4;
} tRegAddr_10;
```

and want to convert all register addresses (given in decimal numbers) to hexadecimal. Other numbers can occur within each `typedef`; therefore I have to consider the `Reg` part as a kind of delimiter. The example should result in:

```
// Register 0x0A:
typedef struct RegAddr_0x0A
{
  uint8 something: 4;
  uint8 something_else: 4;
} tRegAddr_0x0A;
```

My solution is this:

```
class String
  def convert_base(from, to)
    self.to_i(from).to_s(to)
  end
end  

new = text.gsub(/Reg\D*\d*/) do |number|
  number.gsub(/(\d+)/) {'0x'+$1.convert_base(10,16)}
end
```

It works, but:

1. (How) is it possible to do this with one `gsub` only?
2. How can I make the conversion generate 2-digit-hex numbers in upper case, e.g. `10` → `0x0A`, not `0xa`?

Comment: Why are you prepending it with `'0x0x'`?

Comment: @sawa: Because it was a copy and paste mistake ;-) Corrected.

Comment: You may wish to consider selecting the answer that you found most helpful, if any were of value. Oh, wait, sawa deleted his answer, so mine is the only one left.

Comment: @Cary: Yes, sadly sawa deleted his answer instead of improving it :-( Of course if nobody else has an answer, logically I'll have to select yours as the most helpful ;-)

Answer (score 2):

**Code**

```
R = /
    (?:                 # begin non-capture group
    ^                   # match beginning of line
    \/{2}\s+Register\s+ # match string
    |                   # or
    \s+RegAddr_         # match string
    |                   # or
    \s+tRegAddr_        # match string
    )                   # close non-capture group
    \K                  # discard everything matched so far
    \d+                 # match >= 1 digits
    /x                  # extended mode

def replace_with_hex(str)
  str.gsub(R) { |s| "0x%02X" % s }
end
```

The part of the format string for [String#%](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-25) that follows the percent character is: `0`, meaning pad left with zeros, `2` for field width and `X` to convert to hex with letters `A`-`F` in capitals (`x` for lower case).

**Example**

```
str = <<_ 
// Register 10:
typedef struct RegAddr_10
{
  uint8 something: 4;
  uint8 something_else: 4;
} tRegAddr_10;
_

puts replace_with_hex(str)
```

prints:

```
// Register 0x0A:
typedef struct RegAddr_0x0A
{
  uint8 something: 4;
  uint8 something_else: 4;
} tRegAddr_0x0A;
```

**Alternatives**

If you are less fussy:

```
R = /
    [\s|t] # match whitespace or t
    Reg\D+ # match string
    \K     # discard everything matched so far
    \d+    # match >= 1 digits
    /x     # extended mode
```

works as well.

You could also change the operative line of `replace_with_hex` to:

```
str.gsub(R, "0x%02X" % $~[0])
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, especially for giving some comments on it! :-)